# How to scan JAR's, which are loaded at runtime, with Google reflections library?

Tags: java, runtime, classloader, reflections

Is there a solution to configure the reflection library so that it scans also JAR's which are added at runtime with URLClassLoader?

For now, reflections just scans the URLs in the ClassLoader. This is the configuration which I am using  now:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader()));
```

I couldn't find any hints in the doc of the reflections library.

**EDIT:** 
This is how I load the jar File:

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/mkorsch/Desktop/test-reflections.jar");
URLClassLoader urlCl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {f.toURI().toURL()},System.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: And how are these jars added? Do you use an existing mechanism?

Comment: Added an edit to my question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to use the relevant classloader as well,

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("my.package", myClassLoader)).addClassLoader(myClassLoader));
```

Or just:

```
new Reflections("my.package", myClassLoader, scanners, ...)
```

Check it out in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/).